# Wine is installed but running command wine returns "bash: wine: command not found"

Tags: terminal, homebrew, wine

I recently successfully installed wine 3.0 rc2, and double checked to make sure it was installed.

I did this all through commandline using homebrew.

However, when I run the command

```
  wine APP.exe
```

it returns

```
  -bash: wine: command not found
```

I tried

```
  brew unlink wine
```

and

```
  brew link wine
```

but got

```
  Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/wine
```

Any help? It is installed, 100%. I tried reinstalling as well, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you need to add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH because that is where **homebrew** installs programs, so `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. Failing that seek and follow the good doctor's advice with `brew doctor`.

Comment: I have the same issue!